# How to use Chi-Square for a rolling die

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXPBoFDqNVk). The guy said that this kind of test allows us to check whether the experiment occurs by chance or something wrong with the way the experiment is being done. I have done very simple experiment, rolling a die. The following code is for rolling a die in Matlab

```
clear all
clc
N = 150;
exp = N/6;
obs = zeros(1,6);
for i = 1:N
   die(i) = randi(6,1);

   if ( die(i) == 1 )
        obs(1) = obs(1) + 1;
   elseif ( die(i) == 2 )
        obs(2) = obs(2) + 1;
   elseif ( die(i) == 3 )
        obs(3) = obs(3) + 1;
   elseif ( die(i) == 4 )
        obs(4) = obs(4) + 1;
   elseif ( die(i) == 5 )
        obs(5) = obs(5) + 1;
   elseif ( die(i) == 6 )
        obs(6) = obs(6) + 1;
   end
end
%die
obs
for i = 1:6
    Chi(i) = (obs(i) - exp).^2 / exp;
end
Chi2 = sum(Chi);
```

One of the results is

```
obs =
    22    25    22    19    21    41
ans =
   13.0400
```

When I check the Chi-Square table, for `0.05` the threshold is `11.070` which means my result in the code should not rejected. Is this correct? I'm just trying to understand how I should apply this kind of test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13.04 is above your threshold, 11.07: you can reject the hypothesis that the simulated die is fair.  ('cause oh boy it ain't, look at that pile of 6s.  it's most like a 7-sided die with two sides labelled 6)

Comment: is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: I don't know Matlab, but your most likely culprit is your call to randi.

Comment: I've done this in C++ as well, one the attempts is 
`19 18 31 35 33 14
<16.24>`
I don't think there is bias in the experiment. My question is now should I expect the result to be lower than `95%`?

Comment: Something's funny with those too.  But yes: an unbiased result will show a low $\chi^2$ value.

Comment: Wait.  You say this is "one of the results" -- I take it you've gotten many many runs, and this one stood out as having a surprisingly high deviation from normality?  If that's the case, that... happens.  Statistics is not an exact science.  Outliers happen. You should not go *hunting* for statistically significant results; if they're properly significant they'll show up regularly on repeated runs of the experiment.

Comment: yes you're right. This rare results comes after a lot of attempts.